# How to write the actual code from a nested class outside the main class

Tags: c++, class, nested

I would like to keep the code readable by writing the actual code of a nested class outside the main class, Is it possible, and how ?

```
class AA{
   //random code

   class BB : public CC <double> {
      // very long code
   };

   // random code
};
```

I would like to write something like :

```
class AA{
  //random code
  //<declaration of class BB>
  // random code
};

class BB : public CC <double>{
  // very long code
};
```

and the BB class should only be accessible within the AA class...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
class A {
    class B;
};

class A::B {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Nice one. Recalling the concept now.

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like that, but there's a twist actually my B class is more like a "class B : public C <double>" kind of class...

I tried declaring "class B : public C <double>;" in A and class A::B : public C <double> {...} after A but I get a weird error :

"error: expected '{' before ';' token"

Comment: @srsbsns: Do you actually need it to be an inner type? Define it in the implementation file, if you just want it to be hidden.

Comment: @srsbsns: If not, then you have to define it, and can only move member definitions out of it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Yes I'd like it to be an inner type !

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
class AA{
   class BB{
      friend class AA ;
      void VeryLongFunction() ;
   };
public:
    void f(){
      BB bb ;
      bb.VeryLongFunction() ;
    }
};

void AA::BB::VeryLongFunction(){
  cout << "I am a very long function" << endl ;
}

int main(){
  AA aa ;
  aa.f() ;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly I want to remove all the code from the BB class from AA (except one declaration line), but thanks I didn't know this was also possible !