# How to define a nested class outside its parent in C++

Tags: c++

I have two classes, A and B.  Class B has no meaning except to class A and requires private access to A's members, so I feel it should be a private nested class.

Class A is already complicated, so I would like to keep the definition of Class B outside of Class A, maybe in a separate header.

I tried this...

```
class A;

class A::B
{
  int i;
};

class A
{
  class B;

  B my_b;
  int i;
};

int main (void)
{
  A my_a;
  return 0;
}
```

And get `error: qualified name does not name a class before ‘{’ token`.

I try this...

```
class A
{
  class B;

  B my_b;
  int i;
};

class A::B
{
  int i;
};

int main (void)
{
  A my_a;
  return 0;
}
```

And get `error: field ‘my_b’ has incomplete type ‘A::B’`.

This is similar to [How to write the actual code from a nested class outside the main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006830/how-to-write-the-actual-code-from-a-nested-class-outside-the-main-class), but complicated by the fact that class A has a A::B as a member.

Comment: You cannot have a non-pointer reference to a class before it is fully declared (although you can *define* methods later), so this is nothing new.

Comment: "... maybe in a separate header." And then if someone only `#include`d the header for `A`, they would have a defined class whose size they don't know - not good.

Comment: If you can't change anything else about these classes, you'll just have to stick with declaring `class B` inside `class A`. You can still declare any member functions of `class B` externally. By the way, if `class B` requires private access to members of `class A`, then `class A` will also need to declare it as a friend.

Comment: @celticminstrel About friendship - not if `B` is nested in `A`. Since C++11, member classes are just like other members in that they have access to non-public members.

Comment: So in other words, a nested class is implicitly a friend to the outer class? I suppose that's useful.

Answer (score 7):

You can have a pointer to `B` as a member, or a smart pointer. The reason you cannot have a member variable of type `B` and have it defined outside of `A` is that if the compiler have not seen the definition of a class it does not know its size therefore cannot figure out layout for `A`.

Another approach to the whole thing is to use a pimpl idiom, I think it would be ideal here.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know how to solve this directly by having field of type `B`, probably it is impossible. But I know how to solve this if to write a small helper templated class like `InlineIncomplete<>` class below.

The only drawback of such class is that you have to write `my_a.my_b->i` instead of `my_a.my_b.i`, in other words to use `->` operator instead of dot `.`, because InlineIncomplete<> is a wrapper class that wraps original B class, so you have to access contained object through `->` or `*` as in pointers.

But although it looks like pointer it has fully-inlined body, not stored in any Heap or other place. Same like [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) but unlike std::optional, my class has no size (and time) overhead, it has no extra `bool` flag that says if object is contained, because it is always contained inside. Unlike std::optional my class can't be nullified.

To use InlineIncomplete<> you pass to its template two params <T, SizeOf_T>, so you have to know in advance size of T in bytes. Because T type is incomplete by this time, my class can't figure out its size manually (otherwise compile error will occur), hence you have to provide its size as template parameter.

Inside constructor of InlineIncomplete<> already we know size of T hence we can do `static_assert()` that checks if you didn't make mistake in guessing correct sizeof T. So you can't ever be wrong in specifying incorrect sizeof.

I modified your code a bit, swapped definition of A and B, and also replace class->struct so that I can demonstrate `->` access inside main. This change class->struct is not important, only for demonstration purposes.

This InlineIncomplete<> is so useful that could be probably included in future C++ standard library, if someone will propose it, if there are any volunteers for proposal, please go ahead! This kind of class will always solve problems of circular dependencies in classes.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/19vv9dvzd)

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <new>

template <typename T, std::size_t SizeOf>
class InlineIncomplete {
public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    InlineIncomplete(Args && ... args) {
        static_assert(SizeOf == sizeof(T), "");
        new (Ptr()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    ~InlineIncomplete() { Ptr()->~T(); }

    T & operator * () { return *Ptr(); }
    T const & operator * () const { return *Ptr(); }
    T * operator -> () { return Ptr(); }
    T const * operator -> () const { return Ptr(); }
    
private:
    T * Ptr() { return (T*)mem_; }
    T const * Ptr() const { return (T*)mem_; }

    char mem_[SizeOf];
};


struct A {
    struct B;
    
    InlineIncomplete<B, sizeof(int)>  my_b;
    int i;
};

struct A::B {
    int i;
};

int main() {
    A my_a;
    auto val = my_a.i + my_a.my_b->i;
}
```

If you don't mind having one extra field inside A, you can even create a reference to a field:

```cpp
struct A {
    struct B;    
    InlineIncomplete<B, sizeof(int)>  my_b;
    B & my_b_ref = *my_b;
    int i;
};
```

and now it can be used a usual way (without `->` and `*`):

```cpp
A my_a;
auto val = my_a.my_b_ref.i;
```